# Add days to DateTime returns value of 0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-format

This code counts number of records in an MSSQL table where a date is between today's date and today's date + 8 days, but it doesn't work; it returns a value of `0`, but `2` is the right answer.

If I change `DateTime.Now.AddDays` to `7` or less it works as it should.

```
//Ordre klar til bestilling
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) from bestillinger WHERE udlevering BETWEEN @date and @dateadd";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateadd", DateTime.Now.AddDays(+8).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
string result0 = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

con.Close();
MessageBox.Show(result0);

if (result0 != "0")
{
    bestillingToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF1919");
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe take the '+' out of there.

Comment: @alykins sorry, but that is simply not true; `+8` means exactly the same thing as `8`; it is merely redundant, not invalid.

Comment: This I did not know- thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What's the column definition of `udlevering`? What does the data in `bestillinger` look like?

Comment: Don't use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` since a datetime value is expected and not a string. Also, use `Today` instead of `Now`, otherwise the time parts will also be considered.

Answer (score 12):

Don't treat dates/times as strings. Just:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateadd", DateTime.Now.AddDays(8));
```

The problem could well be date/time formats.

Note that you are actually executing it twice for no reason; you can remove the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Finally, don't treat integers as strings:

```
int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
if(count != 0)  { .... }
```

Comment: @user that is almost useless as a statement. What happens? And how is it different to what you expect to happen? If you get a different number: what makes you think your expectation is correct? (If you're routinely treating data as strings, frankly the source data is hugely suspect). What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: I suspect he's actually storing the dates as strings, and not just trying to send them to sql server that way :( Ugh.

Comment: @Joel yes, I fear the same - the idea of someone storing dates in a database as strings in dd/MM/yyyy format terrifies me

Answer (score 8):

Seven days from now, it's still September, and the date looks like this:

> 30/09/2014

Eight days from now, it's October, and the date looks like this:

> 01/10/2014

Pop quiz: does `01/10/2014` refer to October 1st, or January 10th? Obviously, you mean for it to refer to October 1st, but parts of the world (and likely Sql Server) will instead read that as January 10th.

The solution here is that **you shouldn't pass date parameters as strings!** Just removing the `.ToString()` calls entirely is probably enough to fix it in this case, but [I prefer to be explicit about my database types](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today;
command.Parameters.Add("@dateadd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(8);
```

---

Of course, the above fix assumes that you've done the sane thing in your database. You may have made the bad mistake of storing your dates as varchar fields in the first place. If you did that, Sql Server is comparing your fields as strings, and based on your example format anything early in the month is **always** going to be sorted before dates later in the month, even across different months. This means that your example end date came *before* your start date. If this is your problem, you'll need to add a new Date column to your table and write code to update your rows with the converted date values. You'll probably need to coordinate this with fixing other parts of your application that insert, update, and select on this field.

The main lesson to take away from this: **NEVER treat dates as strings!** This applies to *every* level of your application except the presentation tier.